# Python Global variable modification does not work

Tags: python

I am trying to update a global  variable **AUTHEN** which refers to the socket's inputstream.

In the `run()` method, I am trying to modify the AUTHEN's value. However, it never changes when I actually run the program. I am sure my server is did send other message other than **"something"**

```
import threading
import sys
import time
import socket
import ssl

AUTHEN ="Something"
class timer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
        self.ssl_sock.connect(('localhost',9991))
        self.isrun = True
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)


    def send(self,str):
        self.ssl_sock.send(str + "\n")


    def run(self):
        global AUTHEN
        while self.isrun:
            receive = self.ssl_sock.recv(1024)
            AUTHEN = receive
            print("recv ->" +AUTHEN)
        self.sock.close()
        self.ssl_sock.close()


    def close(self):
        self.isrun == False


    def authentication(self,username,password):
        global AUTHEN
        print "Verifing identity"
        self.ssl_sock.send("U&P"+"sprt"+username+"sprt"+password+'\n')
        while (True):
            print AUTHEN
            if(AUTHEN == str("OK\r\n")):
                return AUTHEN   
            else:   
                print "Please Try again"
                break   

def main():
    client = timer()
    client.start()

#LOG IN 
while(True):
    loginMessage = str(raw_input("Please enter username and password as following format: \n username%password \n"))
    username = loginMessage.split("%")[0]
    password = loginMessage.split("%")[1]
    Result = client.authentication(username,password)
    if(Result == str("OK\r\n")):
        print "LOG IN SUCCESSFULLY"
        print "Welcome:\n","Command to be used:\n","-a filename\n" "-c number\n", "-f filename\n","-h hostname:port\n","-n name\n","-u certificate\n","-v filename certificate\n","otherwise input will be treated as normal message"
        break
if __name__=='__main__':
main()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using semi colons in python ??

Comment: @anand java habit...

Comment: When in python, do as it is done in python; also specify which python version you are using.

Comment: And what is the output of that?

Comment: Why not define AUTHEN as self.authen in your object and refer to it that way? Also, where are you calling `main()`?

Comment: you might be overriding `AUTHEN` with your `global` declaration

Comment: Sorry, but if the peer sends `OK\r\n`, this code seems to work correctly. I just tested it with an *interactive* python shell (server socket bound to 9991 in a second idle window) with ssl removed and I correctly got a connection as soon as the peer sent `OK\r\n`. Control your server...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Hello. My server is a java which sends outputstream.println("OK"). And the `AUTHEN = receive
            print("recv ->" +AUTHEN)` shows me "Something" ...

Comment: @RandomDavis I want to use the inputstream as a global variable because I might do something with it according to different input message. Basically the client has to log in first.  However, the inputstream is already running when I call main so I can't refer to it again in `authentication()` method. Otherwise the input thread will be blocked. So I am trying to extract the message from the inputstream

Comment: @SergeBallesta `def run(self):
  
  while self.isrun:
   receive = self.ssl_sock.recv(1024);
   print receive +"!!!!!!!"
   AUTHEN = receive;
   print("recv ->" +AUTHEN);
        self.sock.close();
        self.ssl_sock.close();` I noticed that `print receive` is not being executed, maybe there is nothing coming from the server..

Comment: @SergeBallesta And I mannualy send some message to the client,  it doesn't receive..

Comment: I confirm. In my tests, the first message is always `Something` because nothing has still been received from server. The workflow is: 1/ set up a listening server 2/ launch `main()` client side: get `Something` 3/ send `Ok\r\n` from server 4/ next authentication is successful

Answer (score 0):

You need to call main()

You need to Start() your thread in order to initialize Run() which will set your global variable.  Your thread.start() is in your main() def.

```
import threading

class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global a
        a = 'Test'
    def main(self):
        thread = ThreadClass()
        thread.start()

a= 'funny'
print a

ThreadClass().main()
print a


>>>funny
>>>Test
```

Comment: borrowed sample [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing from your code the two sentences:

```
global AUTHEN;
```